# scheduling in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I want to run my **service in android** only between **8:00 a.m to 5:00 p.m.**.And during this time interval I want to execute any task after ***15 mins*** interval.(e.g. 8:15 a.m. , 8:30 a.m ,9:00 a.m. ...... , 4:45 p.m , 5:00 p.m.). So how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. You will find lots of tutorials about that using Google.